# How operator overloading in c++ works

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I was going through some of the theory of assignment operator of c++.

Let's say

```
class MyClass {
private:
   T1 member1;
   T2 member2;
public:
   // The default copy assignment operator which assigns an object via memberwise copy
   MyClass & operator=(const MyClass & rhs) {
      member1 = rhs.member1;
      member2 = rhs.member2;
      return *this;
   }
......
}
```

and

```
c7 = c6; //member wise copy assignment.
```

Here we are returning the reference to the object during the assignment operation and assigning it the new object `c7`.

However if I my code is somewhat like this:

```
    int a=12;
    int &b=a;
    int c=&b;        //error::invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’
```

Why is this different from the above case??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration

```
int& b = a;
```

declares `b` to be a reference, and makes it reference the variable `a`.

The declaration

```
int c = &b;
```

declares `c` to be a normal `int` variable, and then you try to initialize it to a pointer to `int`. The ampersand `&` does different things depending on context.

---

As for the copy-assignment operator, it's *not* called when you initialize a variable in a declaration, instead it's the copy-constructor being called.

---

When you have a copy-assignment operator, and do e.g.

```
MyClass a, b;

a = b;  // Copy-assignment operator called
```

The compiler basically replaces the assignment with the following call

```
a.operator=(b);
```

In other words, it's a normal member-function call, like any other.

Comment: @Pileborg Can you explain in brief what would happen in the case of operator assignment?Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
c7 = c6; //member wise copy assignment.
```

You said:

> Here we are returning the reference to the object during the
>   assignment operation and assigning it the new object c7.

This is not returning a reference and assigning it to c7. It is calling `operator =` on c7 with a `rhs` parameter referencing c6.

The reason your `operator =` needs to return a reference is so that the result of an assignment can be used in another expression (usually another assignment, but it could be any expression). So you can do

```
c8 = c7 = c6;
```

which will call `operator =` on c7 with a `rhs` referring to c6, then call `operator =` on c8 with the result of that assignment (which will be the returned reference to c7, based on your code).

Answer (score 0):

Your operator overloading was not appropriate. Say this is your operator overloading code -

```
class ABC:
{
public:
    ABC();

    bool operator==(const ABC& ip) const
    {
        if( (this->a == ip.a) &&
            (this->b == ip.b))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    ~ABC();

int a,b;

};
```

Now you can do the following -

```
ABC x,y;
// do new or other operations.
if (x==y)
{return true;}
else return false;
```

Here we are only overloading operator (==), other operators can be overloaded in the same way.